# Shortcut to a specific accessibility feature

Tags: macos, shortcut, automation, accessibility

Is it possible to apply a keyboard shortcut to  toggle on/off a specific accessibility feature of Mac OS X, for instance the Switch Control or the Head Pointer?

Answer (score 1):

For **Switch Control**, see my answer to: [applescript access switch control through system preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66645393/applescript-access-switch-control-through-system-preferences/66646193#66646193)

For **Head Pointer**:

> How is it possible to check the box you mentioned for Head Pointer?

<sup>Quoted question from comment under the OP.</sup>

Test this *example* **AppleScript** *code* in **Script Editor** to see if it works. Then try it again with the `activate` *command* commented out. e.g.: `# activate`

It may only work with **System Preferences** being visible, you'll just have to see.

```applescript
if running of application "System Preferences" then
    try
        tell application "System Preferences" to quit
    on error
        do shell script "killall 'System Preferences'"
    end try
    delay 0.1
end if

repeat while running of application "System Preferences" is true
    delay 0.1
end repeat

tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    reveal anchor "Head_Pointer" of ¬
        pane id "com.apple.preference.universalaccess"
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "System Preferences"
        repeat until (checkbox "Enable head pointer" of ¬
            tab group 1 of group 1 of window 1 exists)
            delay 0.1
        end repeat
        click checkbox "Enable head pointer" of ¬
            tab group 1 of group 1 of window 1
        delay 0.1
    end tell
end tell

tell application "System Preferences" to quit
```

---

**Notes**:

The *example* **AppleScript** *code* can be use in a **Automator** *Service/Quick Action* and assigned a *keyboard shortcut* in: **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services**

Or there are several third party *applications* that can trigger **AppleScript** *scripts*, with assigned *keyboard shortcuts* , e.g. [**FastScripts**](https://redsweater.com/fastscripts/).

<sub>Note that I am not affiliated with the developer of FastScripts, just a satisfied user.</sub>

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: Automator “watch me do” also can automate anything that doesn’t have an accessible  shortcut for scripting or a preference / config file / profile that is addressable directly.

Comment: @bmike, I'm well aware of what a **Watch Me Do** _action_ in **Automator** can do and it cannot do "anything" as you so suggest because there are times when the _hierarchical UI element structure_ changes upon an action taken and then what was recorded fails on playback because recorded events are static and the _action_ is not capable of _dynamic logic_. Also, try recording **System Preferences** > **Accessibility** > **General** then scroll down and select **Switch Control**, then click **Enable Switch Control**. Cont...

Comment: @bmike, Now close **System Preferences** > and play the **Watch Me Do** _action_, it fails! Extract the **AppleScript** _code_ from the **Watch Me Do** _action_ you just record and try it in **Script Editor**, it also fails! The bottom line here is your comment referencing the **Watch Me Do** _action_ is not accurate and the **Watch Me Do** _action_ has limitations.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt correction. I will for sure test well before I edit that in again & very much appreciate the update. We try very hard to rely on config profiles at work because of breakage and time to test W.M.D. + superior robustness of the push mechanism.